# Grep for a character in one element of a vector

Tags: r

Unless I am overlooking something, I cannot find the solution to the following.

If I have the following single element vector:

```
c("133 45123; 4514;25")
```

How can I find the position within this element that has the ";" and " ", such that I can then use substr to obtain:

```
45123;
```

Have tried grep, but that seems to work over a vector of multiple elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x <- c("133 45123; 4514;25")

stringr::str_extract(x, "\\w+(?=; )")
[1] "45123"
```

In Base R:

```
sub(".*?(\\w+); .*", "\\1", x)
[1] "45123"
```

or even:

```
regmatches(x, regexpr("\\w+(?=; )", x, perl = TRUE))
[1] "45123"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Will have to look into what the symbols mean, but very elegant solution, particularly given it is in base r. Accepted your answer. Thanks!

Comment: @onyambu: Why not '"\\d+(?=;)"'. Do we have a specific reason?

Comment: @TarJae That will capture `4514`. OP specifically stated that they want to only capture elements that have `;` and `" "`. Note that the if you use `\\d+(?=;)` if I had used greedy functions eg `gsub` and `str_extract_all` and `gregexpr` then I will have 2 results instead of one. But using `(?=; )` I ensure I just have one result

Answer (score 0):

I found part of the solution. Strsplit() will look through each element of a vector and separate the single element into various smaller vector based on the separator you designate. This can help cut down the element into smaller vectors that you can then use grep() on.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).